# Finding the contour closest to image center in OpenCV2

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am trying to use openCV2 to automatically delineate the contours of churches and cathedrals from static maps.

In a nutshell, I am:

- scraping the building's coordinates from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_church_buildings).
- creating a map centered on those coordinates using Folium, a Python library.
- saving the map as a jpg image.
- applying openCV2's `findContours` method to delineate the contours of the buildings.

I initially assumed that the cathedrals would be the largest building within a few hundred meters, so I sorted the contours by area following [this PyImageSearch tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/):

```
contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0:1]
```

That works like a charm in a few cases, like Saint Peter's basilica:

[image]

However, depending on the city and the chosen the zoom level, I often happen to pick nearby buildings that are actually larger than the church:

[image]

I am thinking of selecting the contour closest to the center of the image.

An option would be to compute the centers of all contours in the map and then identify the closest point to the image city center, but I am wondering if there is an easier solution.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used `cv2.moments(contour)` as shown in [this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/01/opencv-center-of-contour/) to get the center of each contour. Then you can use `distance.euclidian` from the `scipy.spatial` module  to calculate the distance of each contour to the image center.

## Sample Image:

[image]

## Code:

```py
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.spatial import distance
    
    
    sample_img = cv2.imread("sample_buildings.png")
    
    # convert to black and white color space
    sample_img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(sample_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(sample_img_grey, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    #find center of image and draw it (blue circle)
    image_center = np.asarray(sample_img_grey.shape) / 2
    image_center = tuple(image_center.astype('int32'))
    cv2.circle(sample_img, image_center, 3, (255, 100, 0), 2)
    
    buildings = []
    for contour in contours:
        # find center of each contour
        M = cv2.moments(contour)
        center_X = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        center_Y = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        contour_center = (center_X, center_Y)
    
        # calculate distance to image_center
        distances_to_center = (distance.euclidean(image_center, contour_center))
    
        # save to a list of dictionaries
        buildings.append({'contour': contour, 'center': contour_center, 'distance_to_center': distances_to_center})
    
        # draw each contour (red)
        cv2.drawContours(sample_img, [contour], 0, (0, 50, 255), 2)
        M = cv2.moments(contour)
    
        # draw center of contour (green)
        cv2.circle(sample_img, contour_center, 3, (100, 255, 0), 2)
    
    # sort the buildings
    sorted_buildings = sorted(buildings, key=lambda i: i['distance_to_center'])
    
    # find contour of closest building to center and draw it (blue)
    center_building_contour = sorted_buildings[0]['contour']
    cv2.drawContours(sample_img, [center_building_contour], 0, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    
    cv2.imshow("Image", sample_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

## Result Image:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, David! Your solution definitely answers my question. In my case, I had to check that `M["m00"]` was greater than zero for some of the contours prior to computing the center coordinates.

Comment: Very helpful solution, thanks for sharing. I personally had some issues because 'image_center = np.asarray(sample_img_grey.shape) / 2' did not work for me. So I changed it with 
"""moment = cv2.moments(sample_img_gray)

                X = int(moment ["m10"] / moment["m00"])

Y = int(moment ["m01"] / moment["m00"])
#image_center = np.asarray(X, Y)
#image_center = tuple(image_center.astype('int32'))

cv2.circle(img, (X, Y), 15, (205, 114, 101), 1)"""
So in the euclidean distance I just used:
 "distances_to_center = (distance.euclidean((X, Y), contour_center))"