# OpenCV2 to measure distance between objects in an image

Tags: python, list, object, computer-vision, opencv3.0

so I have a program that measures the distance between two objects in an image. However, the program automatically takes the leftmost object as the "reference image". I have been struggling for a while now to change this reference object to be a square at the centre for example.

The only way I can image to do this is by using Python Pillow to calculate the centre coordinates of the image and using these to create a 'square' reference object. However, I have been struggling to do this. I have included the unaltered code below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# USAGE
# python distance_between.py --image images/example_01.png --width 0.955
# python distance_between.py --image images/example_02.png --width 0.955
# python distance_between.py --image images/example_03.png --width 3.5
# python distance_between.py --image images/example_04.jpg --width 1.0

# import the necessary packages
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

def midpoint(ptA, ptB):
    return ((ptA[0] + ptB[0]) * 0.5, (ptA[1] + ptB[1]) * 0.5)

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to the input image")
ap.add_argument("-w", "--width", type=float, required=True,
    help="width of the left-most object in the image (in inches)")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

# perform edge detection, then perform a dilation + erosion to
# close gaps in between object edges
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 100)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)

# find contours in the edge map
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

# sort the contours from left-to-right and, then initialize the
# distance colors and reference object
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)
colors = ((0, 0, 255), (240, 0, 159), (0, 165, 255), (255, 255, 0),
    (255, 0, 255))
refObj = None

# loop over the contours individually
for c in cnts:
    # if the contour is not sufficiently large, ignore it
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 100:
        continue

    # compute the rotated bounding box of the contour
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = np.array(box, dtype="int")

    # order the points in the contour such that they appear
    # in top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
    # order, then draw the outline of the rotated bounding
    # box
    box = perspective.order_points(box)

    # compute the center of the bounding box
    cX = np.average(box[:, 0])
    cY = np.average(box[:, 1])

    # if this is the first contour we are examining (i.e.,
    # the left-most contour), we presume this is the
    # reference object
    if refObj is None:
        # unpack the ordered bounding box, then compute the
        # midpoint between the top-left and top-right points,
        # followed by the midpoint between the top-right and
        # bottom-right
        (tl, tr, br, bl) = box
        (tlblX, tlblY) = midpoint(tl, bl)
        (trbrX, trbrY) = midpoint(tr, br)

        # compute the Euclidean distance between the midpoints,
        # then construct the reference object
        D = dist.euclidean((tlblX, tlblY), (trbrX, trbrY))
        refObj = (box, (cX, cY), D / args["width"])
        continue

    # draw the contours on the image
    orig = image.copy()
    cv2.drawContours(orig, [box.astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.drawContours(orig, [refObj[0].astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # stack the reference coordinates and the object coordinates
    # to include the object center
    refCoords = np.vstack([refObj[0], refObj[1]])
    objCoords = np.vstack([box, (cX, cY)])
       
    # loop over the original points
    for ((xA, yA), (xB, yB), color) in zip(refCoords, objCoords, colors):
        # draw circles corresponding to the current points and
        # connect them with a line
        cv2.circle(orig, (int(xA), int(yA)), 5, color, -1)
        cv2.circle(orig, (int(xB), int(yB)), 5, color, -1)
        cv2.line(orig, (int(xA), int(yA)), (int(xB), int(yB)),
            color, 2)
        # compute the Euclidean distance between the coordinates,
        # and then convert the distance in pixels to distance in
        # units
        D = dist.euclidean((xA, yA), (xB, yB)) / refObj[2]
        (mX, mY) = midpoint((xA, yA), (xB, yB))
        cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}in".format(D), (int(mX), int(mY - 10)),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.55, color, 2)

        # show the output image
        cv2.imshow("Image", orig)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I see this code comes from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/ which has a dedicated chat at the bottom with a specialized focus for questions like this.  I would suggest you direct this question there.

Some suggestions I would give is that you modify the code to specify the object found at the specified image coordinates found via click https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/displaying-the-coordinates-of-the-points-clicked-on-the-image-using-python-opencv/

Comment: Another suggestion is to approach the code with some changes taking something like this into account https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541559/finding-the-contour-closest-to-image-center-in-opencv2

I think the technique your approaching with the Pillow library is a good out of box thinking idea, but it needs to be applied in the realm of OpenCV's existing objects in the code to make any difference to meet your goal.